# Splitting incoming data between angle brackets in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, split

Hi I am new to programming and need to extract data for my school project. The data is coming in from an Arduino device which sends data that looks like this.

```
<call_sign>IVV-HAM</call_sign>
<mission_call>ARP</mission_call>
<absolute_time>13:13:13</absolute_time>
<elapsed_time>43</elapsed_time>
<imu_accel_x>240</imu_accel_x>
<imu_accel_y>196</imu_accel_y>
<imu_accel_z>62</imu_accel_z>
<imu_gyro_x>599</imu_gyro_x>
<imu_gyro_y>1013</imu_gyro_y>
<imu_gyro_z>215</imu_gyro_z>
<imu_mag_x>402</imu_mag_x>
<imu_mag_y>495</imu_mag_y>
<imu_mag_z>447</imu_mag_z>
<imu_temp>453</imu_temp>
```

I need to get rid of the first three lines and then send the remaining code to be graphed. I have tried to Delimit and Split the angle brackets but nothing I know how to do seems to work.
Any help would or suggestions of where I can find an answer (I have been looking on here for a day already) would be appreciated thank you.

```
 public void run(){
                    //create a new Scanner and connect it to the Serial Port
                    input = new Scanner(connectedPort.getInputStream());
                    //HERE I tried to use input.useDelimiter("></")
                    // I also tried to split by creating a string.split but   
                    // it did not work either.
                    //loop indefinitely until you get data from the Serial Port
                    while(input.hasNextLine()){
                        //get line of text from serial port
                        String line = input.nextLine();

                        //dump the raw data to the output text area
                        //taRawOutput.append(Integer.toString(number)+'\n');
                        textArea_RawData.append(line+"\n");
                    }//end of loop

                    //close the scanner object reading from the serial port
                    input.close();
                }//end of methd run()
            };//end of inner class definition

            //start the thread that was just defined running
            thread.start();

        }catch(IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }//end of catch block
    }
```

I tried editing the question to show what I did.

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Comment: PS looks like XML

Comment: After the "new Scanner" I tried to use a Delimiter that went as "input.useDelimiter("></")" but it didn't work so i deleted the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split *before* an open bracket, but not when it's followed by a slash. And you need the split to not consume the bracket. All this can be done with a *look ahead*.

Try this:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("(?=<[^/])");
```

Then every time you call `scanner.next()` you'll read in an entire tag.

The regex means "the following characters are a `<` then a character that is not a slash" and it won't consume any of the input (the match is zero-length, actually *between* characters)

Comment: No explanations, just an advanced regex thrown at a newbie. Serious question: if you would run into such an answer in your moderator role, what would you do about it?

Comment: @GhostCat before you jump to conclusions, I was in a very bad mobile reception area and couldn't post the explanation part (kept timing out). My first attempt at posting died, so I tried (from scratch) again. Now that I'm back on line, I have posted a proper answer. If I saw the original, I would probably ask the poster to explain it.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to forgo a delimited and use a Vector with an "indexOf(">") + 1, lastIndexOf("<")" which I know is outdated but it works for my purpose. It holds the data I need and can sent to different graphs which I need. 
Thank you for your help though I appreciate it.